# Compare two table in JPA

Tags: jpa

Hi I have two tables 'userAccount' and 'userAccountdetail'. The userAccount table primary key is userAccount Id which is primary key and auto increment column of the given table then UserAccountDetail table primary key is userAccountId which is Foreign key and one to one mapping of userAccount table.

My question is , how to get the userAccount table records which is not available in UserAccountDetail table . Any one help me ?

Comment: you do know that JPA is oriented around CLASSES not TABLES? Kindly post the (relevant parts of the) classes.

Comment: can you help me how to construct the query in JPA and get the records .

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mapping from userAccountDetail in userAccount you can do it in JPQL like:

```
select ua.* from userAccount ua where ua.mappingFromDetail is null;
```

how to do a JPA query:

```
String query = "select ua.* from userAccount ua where ua.mappingFromDetail is null;
List<userAccount> resultados = yourDao.find(query);
```

Comment: there is no mapping from userAccount to accountDetail .. i put mapping userAccountdetail to useraccount only

Comment: but detail can exist without userAccount?

Comment: yes without detail we can create the user .. because root or system user means no need to create the userAccountDetail..

Comment: so maybe is better than UserAccount has a mapping to detail isn't it?

Comment: sorry we did not mapping to userAccount to accountDetail so any other option to get the value ?

Comment: don't worry you can create a not in query.. example: select ua.userId from userAccount ua where ua.userId NOT IN (select userIdAccount from UserAccountDetail);

Comment: already i try same query and get the output but i need some other query .. so can u help me ?